# Flask-SQLAlchemy. Create several tables with all fields identical

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask with its SQLAlchemy extension. I need to define several model classes, which will create tables in MySQL database. The tables will only differ by name, all the field names/datatypes in them will be identical. How do I define the classes for all those tables? I'm thinking of some inheritance, but I'm not quite sure how exactly would I do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just define all your columns in [a mix-in class](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixin-and-custom-base-classes):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MyMixin(object):
    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)

class MyModel1(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models1'

class MyModel2(MyMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models2'
```