# SQLalchemy: multiple tables one schema, and dynamically creating tables at startup

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a Flask app, which, at startup, should read some number of tsv files, each of which has the same schema, put them in tables (one for each file), and then users will specify which table/file they want to query, and some number of keys.

I'm not sure how to do this, but the best way seems to be to specify one schema and then, once the app starts, read the files and dynamically create tables for each file. I can't find anywhere in the SQLalchemy docs any mention of how to use the same schema multiple times. Perhaps I need to extend my schema class, but i'm not sure how to do this at startup.

Thanks in advance!

-- EDIT --

It looks like this answers half of my question: 
[Flask-SQLAlchemy. Create several tables with all fields identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877196/flask-sqlalchemy-create-several-tables-with-all-fields-identical?rq=1)

So my question now is: Can you do the above in Flask, and can you do it as the app starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take 2 approaches.

1. **Sub-classing** - You create a base Mixin for schema and subclass it for each concrete tables. This approach is useful, if you expect that in future the schema for different tables might diverge. If a new field needs to be added in only one table you can add it only in sub-class. (variables db, Model etc is used from [flask sqlalchemy quickstart](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#a-minimal-application))

   ```
   class BaseMixin(object):
        name = db.Column(String(80), unique=True)
        field2 = db.Column ...

   class SubClass1(BaseMixin, db.Model)         
        pass

   class Subclass2(BaseMixin, db.Model)
        additional_field_for_subclass2 = db.Column(...
        pass
   ```
2. **Common table for all** - If you are confident that the schema will remain the same for all tables. I would suggest you create one table for all you data, with a additional field **data_source** which will indicate where the row/data came from.

   ```
   class CommonTable(db.Model):
      data_source = db.Column(String(100) ..)
      field1 = ...
      field2 = ...
   ```

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what each of these classes do. There's a lot of magic being put under the rug here. Most importantly, I'm not sure how to manipulate my tables at startup (e.g. create new tables, throw away old ones) which I'd like to do instead of defining classes which might represent tables.

Comment: Each subclass represent one file/table. You have to read one line from file-1 and create object of Subclass1(). Then you can persist this object in database with session.add() and session.commit.