# Attach the same SQLAlchemy table to two models with different binds

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to add two MySQL databases into my Flask app. Unfortunately, these database are almost identical. 
They have same table and column names, but different data.

I am using SQLALCHEMY_BINDS in my `config.py`

```
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'old': 'mysql://[OLD_DB_HERE]',
    'new': 'mysql://[NEW_DB_HERE]'
}
```

And then in my `models.py`

```
class CallOld(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'old'
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['ConferenceCall2']

class CallNew(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'new'
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['ConferenceCall2']
```

The problem is that when I call a query for both tables I get the same results.

For example, both `CallOld.query.with_entities(CallOld.TenantName.distinct()).all()` and `CallNew.query.with_entities(CallNew.TenantName.distinct()).all()`
 return the same.

Interestingly, the output is **always** from the second of the two model classes. Apparently the second class (`CallNew` in that case) overwrites the first (`CallOld`).

How do I attach the same table definition to two models with different binds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877196/flask-sqlalchemy-create-several-tables-with-all-fields-identical, do you have a reason why you have to try and use the same `Table` object, even though the models are meant for different databases. Using a mixin would probably solve this right away.

Comment: These databases already exist and I just need to connect my Flask app to them. The first one is the old, the second is the new one. But their structure and their table names are the same. That's why I'm using the same table name. I will check mixin anyway. Hopefully this will help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [mixin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html) for this:

> A common need when using [`declarative`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.declarative) is to share some functionality, such as a set of common columns...

The reason why the output is always from the second (new) model's bound database is that as you manually define the `__table__` for the two models Flask's declarative extensions [work their black magic](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L602):

```
def __init__(self, name, bases, d):
    bind_key = d.pop('__bind_key__', None) or getattr(self, '__bind_key__', None)
    DeclarativeMeta.__init__(self, name, bases, d)
    if bind_key is not None and hasattr(self, '__table__'):
        self.__table__.info['bind_key'] = bind_key
```

As can be seen the [`__table__.info['bind_key']`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.info) is overwritten in each declarative class that the table is passed to.